# How to make a Django template tag which expands into another (macro)

Tags: django, django-templates

We've got a third-party Django template tag like this:

```
{% frobnicate "foo", "bar", "baz" %}
  do stuff with {{ frobnicator }}
{% endfrobnicate %}
```

Unfortunately, the `do stuff with {{ frobnicator }}` part is repeated every time we use the `{% frobnicate %}` tag.

What's the easiest way to build a tag so that something like

```
{% frobnicate2 "foo", "bar", "baz" %}
```

...expands into the first example?

**Update:** Simple inclusion tags aren't enough. I didn't make it clear in the example above, but I need to be able to manipulate the parameters passed to the expansion.

Comment: Do you mean [inclusion templatetags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)

Comment: @DanielRoseman Maybe? I'm not sure if they can do what I want here. I'll re-read the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a template filter that will render your [custom string instead of a template file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077272/invoke-django-template-renderer-in-memory-without-any-files-from-strings).

**Declare it like this** (this code is tested)**:**

```
#app_name/templatetags/frobnicative_tags.py
from django.template import Template, Context
register = Library()

@register.tag(name = 'frobnicate2')
def frobnicate2(parser, token):
    args = token.split_contents()
    template_string = """
       {%% load my-third-party-frobnicator-lib %%}
       {%% frobnicate %s %%}
          do stuff with {{ frobnicator }}
       {%% endfrobnicate %%}
    """   
    return Frobnicate2(''.join(args[1:]), template_string)

class Frobnicate2(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, frobnicative_args, template_string):
        self.template_string = template_string
        self.args = frobnicative_args

    def render(self, context):
        """
        Dict inside a Context() is empty because we
        need to pass a context in order to render, even if
        the context is empty.
        """   
        return Template(self.template_string % self.args).render(Context({}))
```

Don't forget to replace "*my-third-party-frobnicator-lib*" with a name of an actual third party library that you're loading.

Then you can render the whole whird-party tag sequence using `{% frobnicate2 "foo", "bar", "baz" %}` just as you wanted.

Comment: @a-paid-nerd, I've just fixed two small bugs in my answer.